# Python:how to find the times of a substring's occurrence in a string?

Tags: python, string, substring

Find all occurrences of “USA” in a given string ignoring the case

Given:
str1 = "Welcome to USA. usa awesome, isn't it?"

Expected Outcome:
The USA count is: 2

Comment: `print(str1.lower().count("usa"))`

Comment: thank you sooo much ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.lower()` to lower case your string, then `.count()` for finding the occurrences of `"usa"`

```
str1 = "Welcome to USA. usa awesome, isn't it?"
print(str1.lower().count('usa'))
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: thank you! so we can't ignore the case and need to change it to upper or lower case?

Comment: this is basically ignoring the case.